# How to drag the TextView to the correct target other TextView

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have giving the full code that I have.

The code bellow can drag and drop very smoothly but it is not working like what I need like bellow description.

1. Drag Data Is (Apple, Orage, Ball)
2. Drop target location is (A for, O for, B for)

So, if drag "Apple" drop to "A for" it will be CORRECT and update text to "A for Apple" and Text "Apple" at drag will be hide... but if we drag "Apple" drop to "O for" or "B for" it will be failed because "O for Orange" and "B for Ball".

Based on the below code, what should I add.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="50dp"
android:paddingRight="50dp" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/option_1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/option"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Apple"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/option_2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/option"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Orange"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/option_3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/option"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Ball"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/choice_1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/choice"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="A for " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/choice_2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/choice"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="O for" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/choice_3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/choice"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="B for " />

</LinearLayout>
```

Acvitity:

```
public class picture_to_word_24_color extends Activity {

//text views being dragged and dropped onto
private TextView option1, option2, option3, choice1, choice2, choice3;
public CharSequence dragData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picture_to_word_24_color);

    //get both sets of text views

    //views to drag
    option1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option_1);
    option2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option_2);
    option3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option_3);

    //views to drop onto
    choice1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.choice_1);
    choice2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.choice_2);
    choice3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.choice_3);

    //set touch listeners
    option1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    option2.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    option3.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

    //set drag listeners
    choice1.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    choice2.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    choice3.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
}

/**
 * ChoiceTouchListener will handle touch events on draggable views
 *
 */
private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            /*
             * Drag details: we only need default behavior
             * - clip data could be set to pass data as part of drag
             * - shadow can be tailored
             */
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            //start dragging the item touched
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
} 

/**
 * DragListener will handle dragged views being dropped on the drop area
 * - only the drop action will have processing added to it as we are not
 * - amending the default behavior for other parts of the drag process
 *
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private class ChoiceDragListener implements OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            //no action necessary
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            //no action necessary
            Toast.makeText(picture_to_word_24_color.this, "ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:        
            //no action necessary
            Toast.makeText(picture_to_word_24_color.this, "ACTION_DRAG_EXITED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            
            Toast.makeText(picture_to_word_24_color.this, "ACTION_DROP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view
            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
            //stop displaying the view where it was before it was dragged
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //view dragged item is being dropped on
            TextView dropTarget = (TextView) v;
            //view being dragged and dropped
            TextView dropped = (TextView) view;
            //update the text in the target view to reflect the data being dropped
            dropTarget.setText(dropped.getText());
            //make it bold to highlight the fact that an item has been dropped
            dropTarget.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            //if an item has already been dropped here, there will be a tag
            Object tag = dropTarget.getTag();
            //if there is already an item here, set it back visible in its original place
            if(tag!=null)
            {
                //the tag is the view id already dropped here
                int existingID = (Integer)tag;
                //set the original view visible again
                findViewById(existingID).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //set the tag in the target view being dropped on - to the ID of the view being dropped
            dropTarget.setTag(dropped.getId());
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            //no action necessary
            Toast.makeText(picture_to_word_24_color.this, "ACTION_DRAG_ENDED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: What is your Question please elaborate!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the following code, it should work according to your description in the question.
I have added an extra thing i.e. reset button as I felt it necessary.

picture_to_word_24_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="50dp"
android:paddingRight="50dp" >


<TextView
android:id="@+id/option_1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/option"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Apple"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/option_2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/option"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Orange"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/option_3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/option"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Ball"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/choice_1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/choice"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="A for " />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/choice_2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/choice"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="O for " />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/choice_3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/choice"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="B for " />

<Button 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Reset"
android:onClick="reset"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Picture_to_word_24_color.java

```
package com.example.touchanddrag;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Picture_to_word_24_color extends Activity {

private TextView option1, option2, option3, choice1, choice2, choice3;
public CharSequence dragData;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picture_to_word_24_color);

    //get both sets of text views

    //views to drag
    option1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option_1);
    option2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option_2);
    option3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option_3);

    //views to drop onto
    choice1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.choice_1);
    choice2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.choice_2);
    choice3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.choice_3);

    //set touch listeners
    option1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    option2.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    option3.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

    //set drag listeners
    choice1.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    choice2.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    choice3.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
}

/**
 * ChoiceTouchListener will handle touch events on draggable views
 *
 */
private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            /*
             * Drag details: we only need default behavior
             * - clip data could be set to pass data as part of drag
             * - shadow can be tailored
             */
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            //start dragging the item touched
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
} 

/**
 * DragListener will handle dragged views being dropped on the drop area
 * - only the drop action will have processing added to it as we are not
 * - amending the default behavior for other parts of the drag process
 *
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private class ChoiceDragListener implements OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            //no action necessary
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            //no action necessary
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:        
            //no action necessary
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

            //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view
            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
            //view dragged item is being dropped on
            TextView dropTarget = (TextView) v;
            //view being dragged and dropped
            TextView dropped = (TextView) view;
            //checking whether first character of dropTarget equals first character of dropped
            if(dropTarget.getText().toString().charAt(0) == dropped.getText().toString().charAt(0))
            {
                //stop displaying the view where it was before it was dragged
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //update the text in the target view to reflect the data being dropped
                dropTarget.setText(dropTarget.getText().toString() + dropped.getText().toString());
                //make it bold to highlight the fact that an item has been dropped
                dropTarget.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                //if an item has already been dropped here, there will be a tag
                Object tag = dropTarget.getTag();
                //if there is already an item here, set it back visible in its original place
                if(tag!=null)
                {
                    //the tag is the view id already dropped here
                    int existingID = (Integer)tag;
                    //set the original view visible again
                    findViewById(existingID).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                //set the tag in the target view being dropped on - to the ID of the view being dropped
                dropTarget.setTag(dropped.getId());
                //remove setOnDragListener by setting OnDragListener to null, so that no further drag & dropping on this TextView can be done
                dropTarget.setOnDragListener(null);
            }
            else
                //displays message if first character of dropTarget is not equal to first character of dropped
                Toast.makeText(Picture_to_word_24_color.this, dropTarget.getText().toString() + "is not " + dropped.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            //no action necessary
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
} 

public void reset(View view)
{
    option1.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
    option2.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
    option3.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);

    choice1.setText("A for ");
    choice2.setText("O for ");
    choice3.setText("B for ");

    choice1.setTag(null);
    choice2.setTag(null);
    choice3.setTag(null);

    choice1.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    choice2.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    choice3.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);

    choice1.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    choice2.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
    choice3.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.picture_to_word_24_color, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Don't forget to check for target API level. As I had to add `@SuppressLint("NewApi")`

Comment: Dear Osama Mohammed Shai, I really don't know how to say thank you...I want to say a million thank you for your help. your code working as what I really really need. If I can give you hundred check, i will. Again Thank you so much Osama.

Comment: Hi Osama Mahammed, Based on code above, how can we detect when all drag object is ended?? I mean, I need to finished the job after we already dragged all (Apple, Orage, Ball) to the target dropped.

Comment: If you have more questions then please ask it in new question. I'll try to answer it there.

Comment: Thank you Osama Mohammed Shaikh :)