# Android - Objects Touched In Swipe

Tags: android, swipe

I have a gridlayout of text views. When I touch and swipe I want the text views I touch to change color.

My current code uses an ontouchlistener. It only registers the first one that I touch. All the other textviews I touch in the swipe do not change. I have to touch each one separately for it to work.

Does anyone have a working example of how to get each object I touch in one swipe to change?

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set onTouchListener on your GridLayout and check what TextView is under the finger (by comparing tv coordinates against touchpoint coordinates) and then set it's color how you like while setting all other TexViews to default color.

Comment: This looks like the way to go. Do you happen to have an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement on drag listener.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17349138/1182971) code. If I understand your question this could help you.

Edist this part:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            //put your code to change the colour of your textview
            break;
```