# android drag drop items in a custom listview

Tags: android, android-listview, drag-and-drop

I would like to get the link to any sample suggesting drag drop list item views, with multiple dynamic items/texts. I have googled a lot for it, but got samples with single textview using arrayAdapter.

I instead like to put drag drop on custom listview hence BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter, and the textviews to be populated dynamically in the BaseAdapter's getView(), and drag drop accordingly.

Please guide, as I am facing a lot of trouble doing this.

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I had a ViewPager which dynamically adds items as well. I think you may find this thread helpful. It helped me solve my problem, cheers. [android drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344259/how-to-drag-the-textview-to-the-correct-target-other-textview)

Comment: I am unable to find listview there. I need to drag drop items of listview