# Picure Click to Picture Drag in Android Puzzle game

Tags: java, android, onclick, drag-and-drop

I Have tried with all possible ways which is suggested in StackOverflow
 But i can't able to change from click to drag

OnTouch event is used for click.. and my images get clicked in this. and i can't able to drag and drop the image. i need to drag the image instead of clicking...

I will be much thankful to you. if you help me on this part

i have also tried this scenario's 
[Drag and Drop and OnClick TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628202/drag-and-drop-and-onclick-textview)
But i didn't get any result. so please can anyone help me!!!!!!!

**Can anyone help me in this ??**

```
public class TouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private float xDelta;
    private float yDelta;
    private PuzzleActivity activity;

    public TouchListener(PuzzleActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        float x = motionEvent.getRawX();
        float y = motionEvent.getRawY();
        final double tolerance = sqrt(pow(view.getWidth(), 2) + pow(view.getHeight(), 2)) / 10;

        PuzzlePiece piece = (PuzzlePiece) view;
        if (!piece.canMove) {
            return true;
        }

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                xDelta = x - lParams.leftMargin;
                yDelta = y - lParams.topMargin;
                piece.bringToFront();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                lParams.leftMargin = (int) (x - xDelta);
                lParams.topMargin = (int) (y - yDelta);
                view.setLayoutParams(lParams);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                int xDiff = abs(piece.xCoord - lParams.leftMargin);
                int yDiff = abs(piece.yCoord - lParams.topMargin);
                if (xDiff <= tolerance && yDiff <= tolerance) {
                    lParams.leftMargin = piece.xCoord;
                    lParams.topMargin = piece.yCoord;
                    piece.setLayoutParams(lParams);
                    piece.canMove = false;
                    sendViewToBack(piece);
                    activity.checkGameOver();
                }
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void sendViewToBack(final View child) {
        final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)child.getParent();
        if (null != parent) {
            parent.removeView(child);
            parent.addView(child, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can check on the other things like handling drag,drop instead of this case

Comment: Can i use drag instead of click ? by using the above code?